# python for loop getting letters in a word by using return

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to make a function which will operate like this:

input:

```
 make_nametag('apple')
```

output:

```
 'a*p*p*l*e*'
```

this is my code:

```
def make_nametag(name):
for letter in name:
    print(letter + '*', end='')
```

Are there any ways that I can use return instead? Thanks!

Thanks !

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: are there any ways that I can use return instead?

Comment: Other than concatenating?

Comment: I mean like to function the same thing but using return instead of print. Thank you for that answer by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out by using:

```
def make_nametag(name):
get = int(len(name))
a = ''
for letter in name:
    a+=str(letter + "*")
return a
```

if there are any better solutions, please share.